# detect selected text

Tags: c#, .net

I m  developing winform application with C#.Net.

[alt text http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/566/97354114.jpg](http://img688.imageshack.us/img688/566/97354114.jpg)

How can reach selected text with mouse? Text area is Label Control.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is not very clear, but assuming that the text area is a RichTextBox control, just use the SelectedText property.  You can use the SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties as well if needed.

Comment: thanks. I just need selected area text. It could be string format. I can split and process it.

Comment: All controls that you can select text in have a SelectedText property, and all inherit from TextBoxBase.  However, Label isn't one that you can select text in.

Comment: Good point, I suppose I have just never had a reason to use those properties in anything but a RickTextBox.  Either way, is this solved for you Jack?